# AWS SDK is using default profile instead of specified one

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-6.0

I have multiple AWS profiles locally, I can confirm that either profile configuration works as intended outside my application.

Within my application, I'm attempting to set the profile in the `appsettings.Development.json`, where I can confirm all other environment variables are being correctly loaded from.

```
...
  "AWS": {
    "Profile": "testprofile",
    "Region": "us-east-2",
    "SecretOne": "my/Secret/Key"
  },
...
```

testprofile definitely exists. I can use it with the AWS CLI tool and get the secrets I'm trying to find from my app. When I go to grab them with `AmazonSecretsManagerClient` the client is configured with my default profile.

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSecretsManager>();
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, configurationBuilder) =>
{
    configurationBuilder.AddAmazonSecretsManager(builder.Configuration["AWS:Region"], builder.Configuration["AWS:GoogleIdentity"]);
});
builder.Services.Configure<ApiCredentials>(builder.Configuration);
```

I can even confirm that `builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions()` is getting the expected "testprofile" value for profile.

There's probably just something wrong with my `program.cs` configuration here, but I cannot for the life of me nail it down.

---

**Update** - more information

100% certain this is getting the correct profile as set in appsettings.json

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
```

The constructor for `AmazonSecretsManagerClient` is not recognizing it, instead getting the "default" profile.

```
        using (var client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(_region)))
```

Here, client -> Credentials is the "default" profile.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little convoluted and yet somehow way, way less code than any of the tutorials I was following. It works, but I'll still accept a better answer.

I put this right into my `Program.cs`

```
var chain = new CredentialProfileStoreChain();
AWSCredentials basicProfile;
if (!chain.TryGetAWSCredentials(builder.Configuration["AWS:Profile"], out basicProfile))
{
    throw new Exception($"Could not get AWS profile credentials for {builder.Configuration["AWS:Profile"]}");
}
var client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(basicProfile, builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions().Region);
var cache = new SecretsManagerCache(client);
var secretOneResult = cache.GetSecretString(builder.Configuration["AWS:SecretOne"]).Result;
var secretOneSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SecretOneConfig>(secretOneResult);
```